# unix awk command is not putting comma for the empty values in a csv file

Tags: linux, unix

I have two csv files which look like below:

```
name,Direction,Date
abc,sent,Jan 21 2014 02:06 
xyz,sent,Nov 21 2014 01:09
pqr,sent,Oct 21 2014 03:06
```

and

```
name,Direction,Date
abc,received,Jan 22 2014 02:06
xyz,received,Nov 22 2014 02:06
```

I am combining these two files based on the first column and creating a merged file. Two commands that I am using for the required output are:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'BEGIN{print "name,Direction,Date,currentDirection,receivedDate"} NR==FNR&&NR>1{a[$1]=$0;next} FNR>1{printf "%s%s\n",$0,($1 in a?FS a[$1]:"")}' 2.csv 1.csv

join -1 1 -2 1 -t, -a 1  1.csv 2.csv | sed "s/Direction,Date/currentDirection,receivedDate/2"
```

Both these command are giving me the below output:

```
name,Direction,Date,currentDirection,receivedDate
abc,sent,Jan 21 2014 02:06,received,Jan 22 2014 02:06
xyz,sent,Nov 21 2014 01:09,received,Nov 22 2014 02:06
pqr,sent,Oct 21 2014 03:06
```

But, I want , (comma) to be placed at the empty (unmatched data) places and output should be like:

```
name,Direction,Date,currentDirection,receivedDate
abc,sent,Jan 21 2014 02:06,received,Jan 22 2014 02:06
xyz,sent,Nov 21 2014 01:09,received,Nov 22 2014 02:06
pqr,sent,Oct 21 2014 03:06,,
```

Please notice the commas after the date in the third row. That is needed for my java application to read the new csv file.
Could anyone please suggest what I am missing here?

Comment: a really big +1 for well stated questions with small sample data, expected output, current output, and code!!! Keep posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the awk one-liner (it looks like my codes...)

```
awk ...... FNR>1{printf "%s%s\n",$0,($1 in a?FS a[$1]:",,") ....
```

Actually, change `""` into `",,"`